# Associate a contact with an account

Tags: trigger

I am creating a trigger in which if a contact isn't associated with any account I need to create an account and associate that contact with it. I am trying this way..

```
trigger null_Accountid on Contact (before insert,before update)   
{  
    List<Account> accountList = new List<Account>();  
    List<Contact> contactList = new List<Contact>();  
    for(Contact cont : [SELECT id, name FROM Contact WHERE accountid='' OR accountid=null])  
    {  
            Account acc = new Account();  
            cont.accountid = acc.id;  
            acc.name = cont.lastname;  
            accountList.add(acc);            
        }  

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code :

```
trigger null_Accountid on Contact (before insert,before update)   
{   
    map<String,Account> contactAccountMap = new map<String,Account>();
    for(Contact con : trigger.new){
        if(con.AccountId == null){
            Account acc = new Account();
            acc.name = cont.lastname;  
            contactAccountMap.put(con.lastName,acc);
        }
    }
    insert  contactAccountMap.values();

    for(Contact cont : trigger.new)  
    {  
         if(cont.accountId == null){
            cont.accountid = contactAccountMap.get(cont.lastName).Id; 
        }      
    }  
}
```

Comment: Nice and elegant...

Comment: always happy to help :)